Module '"@clerk/nextjs"' has no exported member 'auth'
I am implementing Clerk Js authentication on my next app.
import Link from 'next/link';
import React from 'react';
import { UserButton, auth, useAuth } from '@clerk/nextjs';
// import { auth } from '@clerk/nextjs/dist/types/server';


const Navbar = async () => {
    const {userId} = await auth();
    const isAuth = !!userId
  return (

However, I am getting an error on the terminal and browser that states: Module '"@clerk/nextjs"' has no exported member 'auth'.ts(2305).
I have deleted auth from the import and imported it from // import { auth } from '@clerk/nextjs/dist/types/server'; instead and it returns no error.
Upon saving, I am getting yet another typescript error: Module not found: Package path ./dist/types/server is not exported from package.
What could be causing this and how can I solve it. I have installed "@clerk/nextjs": "^5.2.2".
Here's the complete code:

import Link from 'next/link';
import React from 'react';
import { UserButton, useAuth } from '@clerk/nextjs';
import { auth } from '@clerk/nextjs/dist/types/server';

const Navbar = async () => {
    const {userId} = await auth();
    const isAuth = !!userId
  return (
    <div>
        <ul className=' flex justify-between m-10 items-center'>
            <div>
                <Link href="/">
                    <li>Home</li>
                </Link>
            </div>
            <div className='flex gap-10'>
                {!isAuth ? (
                <>
                <Link href="/sign-in">
                    <li>Login</li>
                </Link>
                <Link href="/sign-up">
                    <li>Signup</li>
                </Link>          
                </>
                ): (
                <>
            
                <Link href="/sign-up">
                    <li>Profile</li>
                </Link>
                <li><UserButton/></li>
                </>

                )}
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar

Here's my middleware.ts code from Clerk Docs:
import { clerkMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";

export default clerkMiddleware();

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)", "/(.*)"],
};

I imported import { UserButton, auth, useAuth } from '@clerk/nextjs'; and was expecting to succefully use it to authicate a user:
const Navbar = async () => {
    const {userId} = await auth();
    const isAuth = !!userId


import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";

Import it from @clerk/nextjs/server, it has been changed from @clerk/nextjs to reduce the bundle size

I had a similar issue earlier. You probably want to use:

The ClerkProvider component
Any children of this higher order component will have access to clerk-specific hooks like useAuth as well as components like <Signup> etc. to make  your life easier
These client side conveniences will not work unless they are used:

in descendant components of <ClerkProvider>
you put 'use client' at the top of the file for any components using (clerk) hooks, as they are purely client-side features.


As the person above mentioned, the correct import is import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs/server"

The serverside / backend implementation is slightly different.
